# Can't install gnome extensions

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

After a restart I realised that something went wrong with my ubuntu. Ubuntu dock stopped being present (I managed to fix it by reinstall -- sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock) and many gnome extensions have just disappeared / stopped working. (And who knows what else problem do I have.)

Having a closer look, the symptom applies on any extension install attempt. Such an attempt will result in a red error button instead of moving the slider from "off" to "on" in chrome extensions, and weird JS errors unique to every extensions in syslog.

Some random syslog examples:

```
Dec 15 15:02:07 gep gnome-shell[1823]: JS ERROR: Extension dock@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com: TypeError: Shell.GenericContainer is not a constructor#012_init@/home/gep/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dock@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/extension.js:391:22#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/script/_legacy.js:82:27#012_Base.prototype._construct@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/script/_legacy.js:18:10#012newClass@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/script/_legacy.js:114:21#012enable@/home/gep/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dock@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/extension.js:985:12#012_callExtensionEnable@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:167:32#012loadExtension@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:349:26#012callback@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionDownloader.js:234:39#012gotExtensionZipFile/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionDownloader.js:115:13

Dec 15 21:52:36 gep gnome-shell[1790]: JS ERROR: Extension clipper@gnome.besnik.de: GLib.FileError: Failed to open file “/home/gep/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/clipper@gnome.besnik.de/schemas/gschemas.compiled”: open() failed: No such file or directory#012_getSettingsSchema@/home/gep/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/clipper@gnome.besnik.de/utils.js:9:25#012@/home/gep/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/clipper@gnome.besnik.de/extension.js:11:24#012_callExtensionInit@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:425:13#012loadExtension@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:346:27#012callback@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionDownloader.js:234:39#012gotExtensionZipFile/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionDownloader.js:115:13

Dec 15 22:24:00 gep gnome-shell[1790]: JS ERROR: Extension show-ip@sgaraud.github.com: Error: Requiring NMClient, version none: Typelib file for namespace 'NMClient' (any version) not found#012@/home/gep/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/show-ip@sgaraud.github.com/extension.js:30:13#012_callExtensionInit@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:425:13#012_callExtensionEnable@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:145:18#012_onEnabledExtensionsChanged/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:497:18#012_onEnabledExtensionsChanged@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:496:11#012_init/createCheckedMethod/<@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:529:46#012enableExtension@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:194:29#012callback@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionDownloader.js:235:44#012gotExtensionZipFile/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionDownloader.js:115:13

Dec 15 22:19:38 gep gnome-shell[1790]: JS ERROR: Extension temperature@xtranophilist: SyntaxError: missing ( after for @ /home/gep/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/temperature@xtranophilist/extension.js:140

Dec 15 22:22:19 gep gnome-shell[1790]: JS ERROR: Extension pomodoro@arun.codito.in: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' @ /home/gep/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/pomodoro@arun.codito.in/dbus.js:23
```

Any idea how could I fix it? I'm really not in the mood to reinstall ubuntu... many thanks in advance.

Comment: A "red error button": can you be more specific? Where is the terminal output from? What do you do to generate such an error message? Use "edit" to improve the clarity of your question.

Comment: same problem for me too!